# Asset Bundle not loading?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

Hello I am making a game for a school project and I ran int this error. [image]

the code loads the scene I have added it to the build settings as you can see here. 
[image]

please help!

Comment: earthquakeDoge is not earthquake doge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what Everts said in a comment :

> earthquakeDoge is not earthquake doge

You are most likely attempting to load a scene by doing this :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("earthquake doge");
```

You should load it with the exact name specific by the scene asset

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("earthquakeDoge");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be a glitch.  Had the same issue and removed the scene from the build manager, added it again and everything was fine.